# Can't enable cgroups memory controller

Tags: linux, debian, docker, cgroup

I have Debian 8.5 on DigitalOcean with a kernel version `3.16.7-ckt25-2`

I'm trying to enable cgroups memory controller for Docker. I add `cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in /etc/default/grub, run update-grub, reboot the server, but it doesn't work.

Output of `mount | grep cgroup | grep mem` shows nothing when it should show something like: `cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)`

Works fine on AWS with the same kernel version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that with a new version (8.5) of Debian DigitalOcean add a file to /etc/default/grub.d/ where GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT was redefined.

Comment: thank you man, different os, different provider, but same solution. Ubuntu 18.04 in my case. 2 days of work :)